# No such file or directory for setting and getting string array

Tags: android, file

as u see i am trying to set the String array and get it in android it gives me no suchfile/directory  i added the permission in mainfist for external storage use

tried it on my android device and emulator with the same error

sometimes give me" can't instantiate  activity null pointer exception"

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ee);
        String[] descs = {
                "Java T-shirt",
                "Java Mug",
                "Duke Juggling Dolls",
                "Java Pin",
                "Java Key Chain"
            };            

        saveArray(descs);

        String[] s =loadArray();

        tv.setText(s[2]); 
}
public void saveArray(String[] output_veld) {

       try {

            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();                
            File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles");                
            directory.mkdirs();

            File file = new File(directory,"textfile.txt");                
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(output_veld);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e); 
        }
}    
public String[] loadArray() {

         try {
             File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

             File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles");
             File file = new File(directory +"textfile.txt");
             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

             ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
             String[] gelezen_veld = (String[])in.readObject();
             in.close();

             return gelezen_veld;
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
         }
         return null;
}
```

logcat:

```
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.one/com.test.one.TestActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at com.test.one.TestActivity.onCreate(TestActivity.java:50)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-17 17:34:07.884: E/AndroidRuntime(1533):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: Are you sure,there is Directory named "MyFiles"?? I think,you are getting no directory there like that.

Comment: @Hiral there is directory.mkdirs() which make directory

Comment: @user1015086: oh..i missed that.anyways,you will have to check for the directory if it exists or not,before creating,though.

Comment: Try checking it with if(!directory.exists())directory.mkdirs(); and also post your logcat in your question.

Comment: @Hiral the same logcat error!! if i back slashed tv.settext(s[2]) it gives me no such directory

Comment: @Hiral without the logcat error

Answer (score 0):

I think,you missed to create a text file there.Try this:

```
public void saveArray(String[] output_veld) {

       try {

            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();                
            File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFiles"); 
            if(!directory.exist())               
                directory.mkdirs();

            String path=sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFiles/";

            String filePath= path + "textfile.txt";

            if(!new File(filePath).exists())
              new File(filePath).createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(output_veld);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e); 
        }
}
```

**EDIT :**

You should use

```
 File file = new File(directory +"/textfile.txt");
```

in your loadArray method.

Comment: the same logcat error !!! can u test it in your emulator ! because it is really strange!:)

Comment: when i backslash tv.settext ,,, it gives me that error   02-17 18:25:59.354: I/System.out(1728): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/MyFiles/textfile.txt (No such file or directory)
02-17 18:25:59.415: I/System.out(1728): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/MyFilestextfile.txt (No such file or directory)

Comment: and the same on the realdevice!!

Comment: You must use backslash there in your File file object in loadArray method.

Comment: Almost, in saveArray and loadArray you are using two different constructors, see my answer above.

Comment: @SteiveB: I just pointed out where he can be wrong,and thats also for saveArray() but still for some reason,he is getting the error.

Comment: plz try it in your ide and emulator to see where is the error @StevieB

Comment: Do you have this in your manifest,
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

are the files to be shared between apps or private,
what api level are you targetting?

Comment: i found it,,,,,,,,,,,,,after restarting eclipse !! it gave me error WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ,,,i cut it and past it in the same place!! it worked ,, i think google should improve how it deals with XML that's really ugly

Answer (score 0):

This creates the File from two strings and adds the slash between the parts

```
File file = new File(directory,"textfile.txt");
```

This creates the File from one string and does not add slash

```
File file = new File(directory +"textfile.txt");
```

Comment: it says android 02-17 18:32:53.434: I/System.out(1812): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/MyFilestextfile.txt (Permission denied)
02-17 18:32:53.444: I/System.out(1812): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/MyFilestextfile.txt (No such file or directory)

Comment: Use this in both methods File file = new File(directory,"textfile.txt");

Comment: i found it,,,,,,,,,,,,,after restarting eclipse !! it gave me error WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ,,,i cut it and past it in the same place!! it worked ,, i think google should improve how it deals with XML that's really ugly